A natural automorphism of a finite group with two generators?
I am looking for a proof or a counterexample for the following:
Let $G$ be a finite group generated by $f$ and $g$. The map $f\mapsto f^{-1}, g\mapsto g^{-1}$ can be extended to an automorphism $\alpha$ of $G$.
The extension of this map would map a group element $h=w$, where $w$ is a word over $f,g,f^{-1},g^{-1}$, to $\bar w$, where $\bar w$ is obtained from $w$ by inverting each letter.
The statement is true in the free group generated by $f$ and $g$. However, I am skeptical as this would mean that $w=e_G$ implies $\alpha(w)=\bar w=e$ for all $w$, which seems too strong.
If its true I wounder whether it is true for any group $G$ and minimal generating set $S$ that the map $s\mapsto s^{-1}$ can be extended to an automorphism. Minimality is important here as otherwise $S=\{f,g,fg\}$ with any noncommuting $f$ and $g$ yields a counterexample.
Thank you for any help.

I believe the noncommutative group with $21$ elements is a counterexample: let $G = \langle x, y | x^7 = y^3 = yxy^{-1}x^{-2} = e\rangle$. Then the map (call it $A$) is supposed to send $x \rightarrow x^6, y \rightarrow y^2$, so $A(y) A(x) A(y^{-1}) A(x^{-2}) = y^2 x^6 y x^2 = y x^5 y^2 x^2 = x^3 y^3 x^2 = x^5$, which is not the identity it should be.

Just to conclude: there is a group $G$ (of order 21) with an element $f$ that is not conjugate to its inverse by any automorphism, and moreover there exists $g$, such that ${f,g}$ generates $G$.

As a random example, consider the sporadic group $M_{11}$, generated by an element of order $8$ and an element of order $11$. Looking at the Atlas, no maximal subgroup can contain these elements, so they do indeed generate. An element of order $8$ is not conjugate to its inverse, and there are no outer automorphisms of $M_{11}$, so there is no automorphism sending it to its inverse.
EDIT @user44191's example of a Frobenius group of order $21$ is better, because there aren't any automorphisms that invert an element of order $3$. Since every set of generators involves one of order three, all generating sets fail. The reason why there are no such automorphisms is that an element of order three conjugates all elements of order $7$ either to their square or their fourth power, and the inverse of one type is the other type.

I'm sure there are smaller examples, this was just the first one I thought of.

nice, thank you very much. Do you think that there are two generators such that the map extends to an automorphism or do all generating sets fail?
